# TikZ: an arrow with two parts

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I would like to reproduce the following picture using `TikZ`. The arrow is split into two halves, and each half has a particular color and text. The two colors I chose are not important.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This would be done best with a new shape declaration that is made for a second node part, but for now, here is an implementation using the `path picture` and manually specifying the width and height of the arrow.

I thought that with an `single arrow tip angle` of `90` equal head indent and head extend should result in an arrow tip similar to your image, this seems to be not the case.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  two part arrow/.style 2 args={
    shape=single arrow,draw,
    single arrow tip angle=90,
    single arrow head extend=.15cm,
    single arrow head indent=0cm,
%    single arrow head indent/.expanded=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/single arrow head extend},% do not work as expected
%    single arrow head extend=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/single arrow head indent},% do not work as expected
    path picture={
      \pgfutil@ifnextchar[\qrr@twopartarrow@split{\qrr@twopartarrow@split[]}#1\@qrr@twopartarrow@split 1%
      \expandafter\path\pgf@tempa (path picture bounding box.north west) rectangle node [every two part arrow node/.try, every two part arrow node 1/.try] {\pgf@tempb} (path picture bounding box.south);
      \pgfutil@ifnextchar[\qrr@twopartarrow@split{\qrr@twopartarrow@split[]}#2\@qrr@twopartarrow@split 2%
      \expandafter\path\pgf@tempa (path picture bounding box.north) rectangle node [every two part arrow node/.try, every two part arrow node 2/.try] {\pgf@tempb} (path picture bounding box.south east);
    }
  }
}
\def\qrr@twopartarrow@split[#1]#2\@qrr@twopartarrow@split#3{\def\pgf@tempa{[every two part arrow path/.try, every two part arrow path #3/.try, #1]}\def\pgf@tempb{#2}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{every two part arrow node/.style={midway,text=black}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every two part arrow path/.style={fill}]
  \node [minimum height=3cm, minimum width=1.5cm, two part arrow={[blue!60!green!35]text 1}{[gray!50]text 2}] (a) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

#### `single arrow head indent=0cm`

[image]

#### `single arrow head indent=.41cm`

[image]